# double quotations inside of double quotations

Tags: batch-file

Creating a backup from the list(it is much longer), but it treats those spaces as delimiters:

```
for /d %%g in (Batch,Card Views) do (
xcopy "Folder 2022\%%g" "Folder 2022\%%g" /i /q /s)
```

when I put double quotations, getting "invalid number of parameters" error:

```
for /d %%g in ("Batch","Card Views") do (
xcopy "Folder 2022\%%g" "Folder 2022\%%g" /i /q /s)
```

Comment: The comment you're responding to was deleted, but I'm guessing it told you to look at the output of `for /?`, specifically the part at the bottom with the different `~` modifiers. The first one that gets mentioned is just `~` by itself, so `%%~g` is just `%%g` but without the quotes, which is what you should be using.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /d %%g in ("Batch","Card Views") do (xcopy "Folder 2022\%%~g" "Folder 2022\%%~g" /i /q /s)
```